# How to insert data to solr collection using Postman?

Tags: json, solr

Hi I have json data which i want to insert into solr. How can i do that using Postman. I need send a json data and store it into solr core. How can i do that using **POSTMAN**

```
   {
   "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":"BMW"
     },
    {
     "name":"Harry",
     "age":30,
     "cars":"BMW"
       },
      {
      "name":"Pinku",
      "age":30,
      "cars":"BMW"
      }
```

Comment: You post the data in any regular way, either by using the bundled tools in Solr (i.e. `bin/post` etc.) or from your own application, or by using `curl` (which is also available for windows). Any reason why any of these didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

1. POST request to http://localhost:8983/solr/[collection_name]/update?commitWithin=1000
2. Add the header Content-Type: application/json
3. Make sure to create a json array for multiple documents

   [
     {
       "name": "John",
       "age": 30,
       "cars": "BMW"
     },
     {
       "name": "Harry",
       "age": 30,
       "cars": "BMW"
     },
     {
       "name": "Pinku",
       "age": 30,
       "cars": "BMW"
     }
   ]